# preg_match help required

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get some values from the following line...

```
$txt = 'Auction Type: BuyNow, Auction End Time: 09/20/2011 09:00 AM (PDT), Asking Price/Current Bid: $5, Number of Bids: 0, Domain Age: 1, Description: , Traffic: 0, Valuation: $0, IsAdult: false';

preg_match('/(Auction End Time: )(.*)( \(PDT\), Asking Price\/Current)/', $txt, $expiring);
```

I am currently getting $expiring(Auction End Time) only, but I need to get Number of Bids: as well, how should I update it to get results? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match("/Auction End Time: ([^,]*),.*?Number of Bids: ([0-9]+),/",$txt,$m);
// $m[1] == end time (including timezone)
// $m[2] == number of bids
```

I fixed the first one too, because if the decription happened to contain `(PDT)` then it would have broken your regex.

Comment: hello, can you help me to get domain and expiry date from '2011-09-25,$69,climatelawpolicy.net'

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
/Auction End Time: (.*)\(.*Number of Bids: (\d+)/
```